# CORS in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, angular15, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm getting cors errors in ASP.NET core though I allowed any origin.

Code in Program.cs in API project:

```
        policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
```

Web api Framework: net7.0

Front end calling this api: Angular 15

Thank you!

Comment: What errors? Using what code? Post both the JavaScript code *and* the full `AddCors` call. Disabling CORS is a bad idea anyway, you should specify the URLs that *are* allowed. You've only posted part of one of the policies specified in the `AddCors` call

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code snippets. [The middleware order is very important.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order)
Below code could help you fix the cors issue.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyMethod()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials(); //.WithOrigins("http://localhost:63746");
}));
...
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
...
app.Run();
```